# Responsive align list items horizontally without text wrap

Tags: html, css

I have a 100% width container I need to fill with 4 list items. Each list item has an image with text on the right of it. I need assistance aligning each image and text in the center of the list item and aligned center in the containing element. If the browser window is resized the text cannot wrap below the image and still be centered within the container.

I thought 100% container and 25% list items would work for the base sizing but I'm unsure of how to 'unwrap' the text around the image and center each item.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="products">
    <li class="product">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />Asian Food</li>
    <li class="product">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />Indian Food</li>
    <li class="product">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />Asian Stuff</li>
    <li class="product">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />Indian Stuff</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: auto;
background: grey;
}
.products {
margin: 0 auto;
list-style-type: none;
}
.product {
position: relative;
background: white;
float: left;
width: 25%;
text-align: center;
}
```

Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7N5HH/2/

Thank you!

Comment: Text should be below or right-top of image ?

Comment: wrap the text in a span and work with that, and set a min-width in pixels on your .product

Comment: That does fix the text wrapping issue. However, the list items will stack on top of each other if resized. I'd like to keep them horizontal if possible.